# Css not working in Chrome or Firefox but works in IE

Tags: css, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a button on my ASP.net website:

```
<div class="input-control">
    <input type="button" id="btnInvite" value="Invite" name="Invite" class="btn" />
</div>
```

And my css is:

```
.btn {
border-style: none;
border-color: inherit;
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
background-color: green;
overflow:auto;
}
```

This works fine in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox the button does not appear green just grey, why is this?

Comment: Your CSS is applied as expected in Chrome, the input is green, it's 35px high and the width is 100% with no borders.

Comment: Is your css in `<style>` tag? And style in '<head>'?

Comment: What is not working in chrome or FF? please be specific.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the problem?

Comment: Sorry dudes, the button does not appear green its just gray

Comment: Do you have any other css files or styles defined and included ***after*** this css declaration? Maybe is this styles rewritten... Try right click on button (input element in browser) -> inspect element and check applied styles...

Comment: My css is included as follows: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Examples/Example 1/styles.css" />

Comment: As i said best choice in this situation is `inspect element` in browser and search in applyed styles... Is hard to guess what can it be... It can be a lot of things - javascript sets styles after load css, others css files that override your styles...

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because you forgot the `border-width` value.
I assume IE is automatically adding a `border-width: 1px;` by default, while Chrome and Firefox dont.

Add this to your current code:

```css
.btn {
border: 1px solid inherit;
}
```

This should be the result:

```css
.btn {
border: 1px solid inherit;
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
background-color: green;
overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-control">
    <input type="button" id="btnInvite" value="Invite" name="Invite" class="btn" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not saying your random guess is wrong but how do you know OP doesn't want the CSS applied as shown in question? Unless OP states any different I'm assuming the issue is that the CSS shown is **not** applied as expected in Chrome. OP did not mention anywhere anything about wanting a border.

Comment: @Fran thats true, but OP didnt really define what the problem is, just trying to help by saying what I assume would be an answer to the question.

Comment: Post an answer ones you know what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question the button does not appear green just grey in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: can you post pictures?